# OSS object oriented alternatives to oracle database

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, database

I want to know if oracle style object oriented database code can be written in mysql, postgresql or any OSS database softwares. I don't want to install the massive oracle db on my ubuntu to learn minimum database programming

EDIT1: After installing orafce when I did the following

```
CREATE TYPE addr_obj_typ AS OBJECT (
    street          VARCHAR2(30),
    city            VARCHAR2(20),
    state           CHAR(2),
    zip             NUMBER(5));
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "object"
LINE 1: create type addr_obj_typ as object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres is probably closest to Oracle, especially if you install the Oracle support functions for PostgreSQL

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4-orafce
```